# How to pass a class extending React.Component as a property to render it (using babel)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsx

This issue is only reproducable in babel (using babel-runtime-6.26.0).

Having the following structure

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
// ...
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.component();
  }
}

// somewhere:
<Bar component={Foo} />
```

worked and works for me in general, but when switching to babel I get the error message:
`TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` in `(classCallCheck.js:7)`. I've read that this is spec compliant behavior, but it does work outside of the babel environment.

Btw, if I use functional stateless components it works, of course. But I can't guarantee that the consumer of my lib is providing such a component and not a class based one.

- How can I approach this using babel?
- Is there a different pattern to use to pass components via properties? I believe it's common practice to pass in classes/class constructors via props to components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component can be either a function or a class. And ES6 classes cannot be called without `new`, at least the ones that are spec-compliant (this includes native and Babel classes).

This is not a problem since components shouldn't be instantiated manually. Both function and class components will be properly handled by `ReactDOM.render`:

```
class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Component = this.props.component;
    return <Component/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: so how do you do this with standard dom nodes, eg `span`?  `const Component = ReactDom.span` doesn't work, neither does `const Component = <span>` (of course).

Comment: It's supposed to be a component, and DOM node is an object, not a component. You can pass custom component, `<Bar component={() => <h1/>} />`. Or even better, built-in component string (which supported HTML elements basically are), `<Bar component={'h1'} />`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `React.createElement(this.props.component, props)` instead.

Here's a working example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() { return "Foo" }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(this.props.component, {})
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Bar component={Foo} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

*https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQGQYZ*